# Application Class in IOS Swift

Tags: android, ios, swift

In android, you can define a class and extend with "Application" class. In this class you can declare app level fields and methods. In this class you also have access to the Application Context and there is a method which is invoked on the start of application. Sample of this is given below:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static Context sContext;

    private static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return sContext;
    }


    public static InterstitialAd getInterstitialAd() {
        return mInterstitialAd;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        sContext = getApplicationContext();

        MobileAds.initialize(this, sContext.getString(R.string.ADMOB_APP_ID));

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(sContext.getString(R.string.interstitial));
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
        });

    }

}
```

What is corresponding thing in IOS?

Comment: Show some of your code what you worked on it to get the desired result

Comment: wings, android code or Ios code?

Comment: you can show both but marked it which one is android or iOS

Comment: wings, I can't show ios code because this is exactly I need. Corresponding IOS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS, You can do configuration inside AppDelegate File in below method.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
          //Here You Can Configure
            return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define class level methods in separate file in iOS and you can call it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() in AppDelegate file.